# Can i boost gaming performance

Tags: windows-8.1, gaming

i have a pc with 2 gb DDR3 ram and dual core processor.intel hd graphics 3000 series. Can I boost gaming performance with windows page file size?

Comment: thanks for down voting if you don't mind please tell me about my problem

Comment: I didn't downvote, but what makes you think the windows page file size would have a significant effect here?

Comment: sorry sir i don't know more about page file so i just ask for is any possibility for that.it's related to virtual memory so just asked for a good solution.

Comment: @AkhilJayakumar - Which is the reason you are getting down votes because you have not done your research.  No;  Increasing the page file given your hardware specifications will have very little effect on your gaming performance.  Your hardware is extremely poor for that purpose.  Even if you added more memory you would see virtual zero performance increase due to the iGPU you have.

Comment: ok now i got a better answer .but sir i have a doubt.is superuser consider as an endpoint for solving problems.suppose if i don't have much time to research can i ask questions on it.

Comment: @AkhilJayakumar - We expect you to perform some amount of research before asking the question so you can answer questions like "what makes you think increasing the page file will help?".  **You had that idea for a reason.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing just the page file will not do anything to help performance. In fact in certain situations it may worsen it due to the additional read/writes on the hard drive.
So just leave the page file alone and allow Windows to work it out on its own.

Unfortunately your machine is a little underpowered for most games these days due to the integrated graphics and the 2GB of RAM. 
Try upgrading your RAM to 4 or 8GB and upgrade to a proper dedicated graphics card.
If you have a laptop and this is not possible, then your only hope is to play games at the lowest quality or purchase a new machine.

Other things you could try is updating Graphics drivers to the latest settings and removing as many running programs as possible. (e.g Antivirus, although I wouldn't recommend it if you also connect to the internet.) However even with this I doubt your performance will increase by much.

Comment: Silk purse answer to sow's ear question ...& polite too ;-) Nice Badge as well, if you can get some more upvotes on this one - http://superuser.com/help/badges/47/reversal